# Configure WebStorm/PHPStorm to know about paths

Tags: css, less, phpstorm

In my file, I refer to compiled CSS files like this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css"/>
```

However, I'm using LESS, so the file is actually `styles/style.less`. It then gets compiled and put together by a build command later.

Is there a way that I can let PHPStorm know about this mapping so I don't get false errors (and thus allows potential real errors to show up)?

Comment: It doesn't change the fact that the actual file you're linking needs to exists anyway. Or am I misunderstanding your position?

Comment: This is a software configuration question, not a programming question.  Stack Overflow isn't the right forum for this.

Comment: *"However, I'm using LESS"* -- means nothing. File must be there/present, otherwise inspection is correct and file is not found (P.S. **File Watcher plugin** can execute such compilation on each .less file modification).

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/36815022/1065300 maybe can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have turned on a file watcher for less, `.css` files are already complied and thus, you should be getting no errors in the first place. If you have a `.less` file, then it will automatically have a `.css` file. You should be getting no errors or warnings in the first place if you have done this. Otherwise, turn on your file watcher.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't use the watcher. I have a grunt build task which automatically builds them and puts them in the correct place (which isn't the same folder the CSS is in).

Comment: *"I don't use the watcher."* So what? You still have final CSS somewhere, right? Or you compiling LESS only on remote server, after deployment (which is very odd -- I see no reasons why it cannot be compiled locally in advance)? If that's the case -- then no luck for you. Your only choice is to try to disable that inspection completely...

Comment: Not compiling locally makes lots of sense. There is no reason I need CSS on my own machine. If I add the watchers, then I get garbage CSS I have to make sure stays out of my repo, have to make sure everyone else working on the project has the watcher configured the same way I do, etc.