# PhpStorm: group/nest *.map files under source LESS (along with *.css files)

Tags: css, intellij-idea, less, phpstorm

Currently PhpStorm nests the generated `*.css` file under the `*.less` file when the file watcher is configured.

Is there any way to get the `*.map` file under there as well?

Example:

[image: css file nested under less file]

Is it one of these settings in the `less.jar > plugin.xml` file?

```
<idea-plugin version="2">
  <name>LESS support</name>
  <id>org.jetbrains.plugins.less</id>
  <category>HTML/JavaScript Development</category>
  <vendor>JetBrains</vendor>
  <description>
      <![CDATA[
      This plugin supports <a href="http://lesscss.org/">LESS</a> dialect of CSS that extends it with dynamic behavior such as variables, mixins, operators and functions.
      The following features are available:
        <ul>
        <li>Dedicated file type.</li>
        <li>LESS page under the Code Style node of the Settings/Preferences dialog.</li>
        <li>Syntax and error highlighting.</li>
        <li>Code formatting and folding.</li>
        <li>Code completion.</li>
        </ul>
      ]]>
   </description>
  <depends>com.intellij.css</depends>
  <depends>com.intellij.modules.lang</depends>
  <depends optional="true" config-file="less-watcher.xml">com.intellij.plugins.watcher</depends>
  <depends optional="true" config-file="less-copyright.xml">com.intellij.copyright</depends>

  <extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <completion.contributor language="CSS" implementationClass="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.completion.LessCompletionContributor"/>
    <completion.contributor language="CSS" implementationClass="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.completion.LessDumbAwareCompletionContributor"/>
    <lang.implementationTextSelectioner language="LESS" implementationClass="com.intellij.psi.css.CSSImplementationTextSelectioner"/>
    <css.structureViewChildrenProvider implementation="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.fileStructure.LessStructureViewElementsProvider"/>

    <errorHandler implementation="com.intellij.diagnostic.ITNReporter"/>
    <lang.braceMatcher language="LESS" implementationClass="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.editor.LessBraceMatcher"/>
    <typedHandler implementation="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.editor.LessBraceInterpolationTypedHandler" id="lessInterpolationTypedHandler"/>
    <typedHandler implementation="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.editor.LessTypedHandler"/>
    <gotoSymbolContributor implementation="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.LessGotoSymbolContributor"/>
    <annotator language="LESS" implementationClass="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.annotator.LessColorAnnotator"/>
    <fileTypeFactory implementation="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.LESSFileTypeFactory"/>
    <lang.parserDefinition language="LESS" implementationClass="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.parser.LESSParserDefinition"/>
    <lang.syntaxHighlighterFactory language="LESS" implementationClass="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.highlighting.LessSyntaxHighlighterFactory"/>
    <lang.ast.factory language="LESS" implementationClass="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.psi.impl.LESSTreeElementFactory"/>
    <lang.commenter language="LESS" implementationClass="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.LESSCommenter"/>
    <psi.referenceContributor implementation="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.references.LESSReferenceContributor"/>
    <lang.findUsagesProvider language="LESS" implementationClass="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.usages.LESSFindUsagesProvider"/>
    <renameInputValidator implementation="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.rename.LESSRenameInputValidator"/>
    <extendWordSelectionHandler implementation="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.editor.LessExtendWordSelectionHandler"/>
    <colorSettingsPage implementation="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.highlighting.LESSColorsPage"/>
    <lang.braceMatcher language="LESS" implementationClass="com.intellij.psi.css.impl.util.editor.CssBraceMatcher"/>
    <lang.foldingBuilder language="LESS" implementationClass="com.intellij.psi.css.impl.util.editor.CssFoldingBuilder"/>
    <codeInsight.parameterInfo language="LESS" implementationClass="com.intellij.psi.css.parameterinfo.CssParameterInfoHandler"/>
    <enterHandlerDelegate implementation="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.editor.LESSEnterHandler" order="after EnterBetweenBracesHandler"/>
    <quoteHandler fileType="LESS" className="com.intellij.psi.css.impl.util.editor.CssQuoteHandler"/>
    <css.elementDescriptorProvider implementation="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.descriptors.LessElementDescriptorProvider" 
                                   order="last, before cssElementDescriptorProvider"/>
    <codeStyleSettingsProvider implementation="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.settings.LESSCodeStyleSettingsProvider"/>
    <langCodeStyleSettingsProvider implementation="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.settings.LESSLanguageCodeStyleSettingsProvider"/>
    <lang.formatter language="LESS" implementationClass="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.formatter.LessFormattingModelBuilder"/>
    <spellchecker.support language="LESS" implementationClass="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.spellchecking.LessSpellcheckingStrategy"/>
    <spellchecker.bundledDictionaryProvider implementation="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.spellchecking.LessBundledDictionaryProvider"/>
    <usageTypeProvider implementation="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.usages.LessUsageTypeProvider"/>
    <problemFileHighlightFilter implementation="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.highlighting.LessProblemFileHighlightFilter"/>
    <breadcrumbsInfoProvider implementation="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.editor.LessBreadcrumbsInfoProvider"/>
    <previewHintProvider implementation="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.editor.LessPreviewHintProvider"/>
    <embeddedTokenTypesProvider implementation="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.LessTokenTypesProvider"/>
    <include.provider implementation="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.include.LessFileIncludeProvider"/>
    <internalFileTemplate name="Less File"/>

    <stubIndex implementation="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.psi.stubs.LessMixinIndex"/>
    <stubIndex implementation="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.psi.stubs.LessVariableIndex"/>
    <stubElementTypeHolder class="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.LESSElementTypes"/>

    <lang.inspectionSuppressor language="LESS" implementationClass="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.inspections.suppress.LessInspectionSuppressor"/>
    <annotator language="LESS" implementationClass="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.annotator.LessErrorsAnnotator"/>
    <annotator language="CSS" implementationClass="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.annotator.LessErrorsAnnotator"/>
    <localInspection language="LESS" bundle="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.LESSBundle"
                     key="inspections.unresolved.variable.name"
                     groupKey="inspections.group.name" enabledByDefault="true" level="WARNING"
                     implementationClass="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.inspections.LessUnresolvedVariableInspection"/>
    <localInspection language="LESS" bundle="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.LESSBundle"
                     key="inspections.unresolved.mixin.name"
                     groupKey="inspections.group.name" enabledByDefault="true" level="WARNING"
                     implementationClass="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.inspections.LessUnresolvedMixinInspection"/>
    <localInspection language="LESS" bundle="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.LESSBundle"
                     key="inspections.resolved.without.imports.name"
                     groupKey="inspections.group.name" enabledByDefault="true" level="WEAK WARNING"
                     implementationClass="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.inspections.LessResolvedByNameOnlyInspection"/>
  </extensions>

  <extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij.css">
    <supportedFileTypesProvider implementation="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.index.LessSupportedFileTypesProvider"/>
    <cssInspectionFilter language="LESS" implementationClass="org.jetbrains.plugins.less.inspections.LessCssInspectionFilter"/>
  </extensions>
</idea-plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it has no relation to LESS plugin descriptor. And, yes, sure it is possible. All you need is to make sure that the pattern for `.map` file is is specified in '`Output paths to refresh`' field of your file watcher. Like

```
$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.map
```

Comment: For SCSS you would want to use something like `$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map`

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the configuration suggested by Iena doesn't work properly, to generate the file .map I configured the settings of the file watcher in this way:

**Arguments:**

```
--no-color $FileName$ 
--source map=$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map  
-source-map-url=$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map
```

**Output paths to refresh:**

```
$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map
```

Is important that map filename contains the .css path in this way:

```
filename.css.map
```

The **--source-map=filename** command generate the .map file and **-source-map-url=filename** link it in the generated css file.

Here the configuration of my file watcher:

[image]

I hope can be useful.

Good code

D.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution it: use flags in arguments

> --source-map-less-inline --source-map-map-inline

It will store the maps inside of css files

However better solution use grunt/gulp builder...